# Not able to open thumb-nail image on mobile device

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.5

[Website](http://niraame.com/fashion/jockey-collections/men/jockey-charcoal-melange-black-fashion-men-vest-us27.html#)
I am using a Magento website which is not able to open the thumb-nail images on the mobile devices. I changed the css file for different resolutions inside the media block but still not able to open the images. 
[image: The images inside the red square are not opening in the mobile devices. Whenever i click on any of those images nothing happens.]

The images inside the red square are not opening in the mobile devices. Whenever i click on any of those images nothing happens.
The image are opening in the desktop for all size of display.
Is it happening because of wrong css code or some other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your resolution for that size add proper image width and height in CSS.

Comment: Image width is correctly set for different resolutions. Any other solutions

Comment: Explain to the op what might be wrong. OP have clearly mentioned that he already checked and did the required modification in the css code.